# How to efficiently search a sortedset with an inequality?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sortedset

Ok say I have a strongly typed SortedSet of type int. I want to find the largest number in the set that is less than x.

Maybe this is the wrong data structure for this but my intuitive thinking is that I have a sorted collection. Surely it makes sense that I should be able to do this type of search via the .NET framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `SortedSet` does not provide direct access by index you have to rely on enumeration (linear search - O(n)). One possibly better method is to use [SortedSet.GetViewBetween](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `Last`, but it does not look like you can get last element without enumerating all elements in view anyway.

Collection with direct access by index (i.e. `List`) would let you do binary search with O(lg n) performance - so if you need to search a lot copying to list could with `ToList` give better overall performance when using [List.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which give you position of next element to one you are looking for).

```
// starting sample for BinarySearch approach  
// not handling case where item not in the list (x = 1).
// List have to be sorted which is the case starting from sorted set: sortedSet.ToList()
var list = new List<int>{ 1,3, 5, 7, 8,9}; 
var index = list.BinarySearch(8);
Console.WriteLine(index < 0 ? list[~index - 1] : list[index-1]);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the list must be ordered before executing the BinarySearch - from the remarks section of the msdn page: "The List<T> must already be sorted according to the comparer implementation; otherwise, the result is incorrect."

Comment: @zohar OP starts with SortedSet so ToList on such collection will produce sorted list. Indeed if starting from some other data then sorting is first step - but that would be even worse than original linear search.

Comment: I totally agree with you, That's why I've upvoted your answer, but that's also what I think it's worth mentioning - your example didn't use `.ToList()` on the ordered set...

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, use Linq's `LastOrDefault` extension method:

```
var lastBefore = set.LastOrDefault(num => num < x); // x is your search number
if (lastBefore < set.ElementAt(0))
{
    // Nothing in the set is smaller
}
else
{
    // lastBefore is the last number smaller then search number
}
```

Comment: Note that this is O(n) even if collection is sorted and normally one would expect O(lg n) performance, but that is best result with `SortedSet` to my knowledge.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes disappointing they don't have O(log n) search methods for SortedSet to leverage the data structure!